# Calling a particular PHP function on form submit

Tags: php, isset

I was trying to call a particular php function in submit of a form both the form and php scripts are in same page. My code is below.(it is not working and so I need help)

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="display()">
        <input type="text" name="studentname">
        <input type="submit" value="click">
    </form>
    <?php
        function display()
        {
            echo "hello".$_POST["studentname"];
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In the following line

```
<form method="post" action="display()">
```

the action should be the name of your script and you should call the function, Something like this

```
<form method="post" action="yourFileName.php">
    <input type="text" name="studentname">
    <input type="submit" value="click" name="submit"> <!-- assign a name for the button -->
</form>

<?php
function display()
{
    echo "hello ".$_POST["studentname"];
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   display();
} 
?>
```

Comment: Error : The requested URL /path/to/update() was not found on this server.

Comment: @MadanBhandari Don't write the name of function in the method of the form.

Comment: If you write name of function in action, it looks the this in root directory and didn't go to if(isset) statement. Kindly remove the function name.

Comment: @SalmanMushtaq, have you read the answer properly, the function name is not in action, `<form method="post" action="yourFileName.php">`.

Answer (score 10):

you don't need this code

```
<?php
function display()
{
echo "hello".$_POST["studentname"];
}
?>
```

Instead, you can check whether the form is submitted by checking the post variables using `isset`.

here goes the code

```
if(isset($_POST)){
echo "hello ".$_POST['studentname'];
}
```

click here for the php manual for [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Wouldn't this execute the function on refreshing the page? Not that on this case is dangerous, but I am doing a save function.

Comment: This will echo null values when refreshing, better use isset($_POST['submit']

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your script is named x.php, try this

```
<?php 
   function display($s) {
      echo $s;
   }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="x.php">
            <input type="text" name="studentname">
            <input type="submit" value="click">
        </form>
        <?php
           if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
           {
               display();
           } 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is run on a server, Your browser is a client. Once the server sends all the info to the client, nothing can be done on the server until another request is made.

To make another request without refreshing the page you are going to have to look into ajax. Look into jQuery as it makes ajax requests easy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function on clicking of submit button then you have
to use ajax or jquery,if you want to call your php function after submission of form
you can do that as :

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="display()">
<input type="text" name="studentname">
<input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
<?php
function display()
{
echo "hello".$_POST["studentname"];
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
       display();
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'Hello World';
    } 
?>

<html>
     <body>
         <form method="post">
             <input type="text" name="studentname">
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="click">
         </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, and perhaps a not so good procedural coding one, is to send the "function name" to a script that then executes the function.   For instance, with a login form, there is typically the login, forgotusername, forgotpassword, signin activities that  are presented on the form as buttons or anchors.   All of these can be directed to/as, say,

```
weblogin.php?function=login
weblogin.php?function=forgotusername
weblogin.php?function=forgotpassword
weblogin.php?function=signin
```

And then a switch statement on the receiving page  does any prep work  and then dispatches or runs the (next) specified function.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with select and option. Each option-value contains the **path to a php-file** which contains the function to run ánd the call to that function:

```
function myFunction() {
    do something
}
```

and:

```
myFunction();
```

For every function that I want in my options I make a separate file containing that function and the call to it.

Now I declare `$_POST['optionvalue']` to a variable which I called `$function`.

And somewhere down the page I have an article which contains:

```
if isset($_POST['functions']) {
include $function;
}
```

And the function will be executed there (like an echo or whatever (I show arrays that are created by the functions)).

I know: everything needs to be validated if you have others use it too, which I don't, I use this only on localhost.