# how to include two submit buttons for a form with different action

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is my scenario :

I have a html form on my main page where user can enter the data and and submitting the form using post method.

```
<form  id="main" name="main" action="#text" method="post" > 


    //codes goes here


    <input  id="generate" type="submit"  name="script" value="create output" />

</form>
```

And the PHP code to process above form is

```
     <?php 

echo '<form action="#text" method="post">'; 

echo '<textarea onclick="this.select()" name="output_textarea" id="output_textarea" cols="100" rows="25" readonly>';

//above form inputs will echo in this textarea

<-------PHP codes for download here---->
<-------PHP codes for email here---->


<input type="submit" id="download"  value="Download" name="download"></input>
<input type="submit" id="send"  value="send" name="send"></input>

echo '</textarea>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

I am echoing the form output to a textarea and I need to have
a download button 
a email button

to save\send the textarea. Here is issue I am facing is both the submit buttons on the second page executing download php function, not email.

So, How can I assign two separate functions for two submit functions ? download and email ?

I am not using separate php page here instead of that using php code on the same page where I add html.

Comment: Have a look at this, may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328354/calling-a-particular-php-function-on-form-submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons are only added to the $_POST when and if they are pressed, and as you can only press one button at a time,

you can just do this or something like it:-

```
if ( isset( $_POST['download'] ) ) {
    do_dowload_stuff();
}

if ( isset( $_POST['email'] ) ) {
    do_email_stuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['download'])){
    // download code here
    echo "Download ".$_POST['output_textarea'];
} elseif(isset($_POST['send'])){
    // email code here
    echo "Email ".$_POST['output_textarea'];
}


echo '<form action="#text" method="post">'; 
    echo '<textarea onclick="this.select()" name="output_textarea" id="output_textarea" cols="100" rows="25" readonly></textarea>';
    echo '<input type="submit" id="download"  value="Download" name="download"/>';
    echo '<input type="submit" id="send"  value="send" name="send"/>';
 echo '</form>';
?>
```