# CSV to Download

Tags: php, html, csv

**My HTML:**

```
<h2>Download Example CSV - IN DEVELOPMENT (not working yet)</h2><br />
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" name="example-csv" value="Download Example" />
</form>
```

**My PHP:**

```
function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename = "example.csv", $delimiter=",") {
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

    // open the "output" stream
    // see http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-unknown-descriptioq
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ($array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($f);
}

if(isset($_POST['example-csv'])) {
    $data = array (
                array('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'),
                array('test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3',)
    );
    array_to_csv_download($data);
}
```

**What Happens:**

When I click the Download Example submit button it gives me a file, example.csv.   This file is pretty much all code for the current page I am on including all javascript, HTML, and anything else sent to the browser.

I can ctrl+F find the actual data I want in the mess.

**My Question:**

Why am I getting all the code for the page instead of just the simple CSV I am looking for?

**Resources used to get to the point I am at:**

[How to create and download a csv file from php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251625/how-to-create-and-download-a-csv-file-from-php-script)

[Calling a particular PHP function on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328354/calling-a-particular-php-function-on-form-submit)

**Final Notes:**

I adapted the resources above to my needs, but can't seem to get what I am looking for.  I hope this is detailed enough.  Please ask for clarification if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to change your server code to not also serve HTML.

Comment: If you're calling the same page with your form, won't your code already have output all the stylesheets and HTML before it even gets to your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is simply that you have to add an *exit* or *die* after the *fclose* then the html-code will not served after the file-data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you file structure is, but this is how it should be

**Your HTML file:**

```
<h2>Download Example CSV - IN DEVELOPMENT (not working yet)</h2><br />
<form method="post" action="ServeFile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" name="example-csv" value="Download Example" />
</form>
```

**PHP file ServerFile.php:**  It is the file PHP you put above, just make sure no spaces nothing before `<?php and at the end.. (simply omit php closing tag ?> )`

Since you are sending headers (header(..)) no output, even a space, should be sent before headers are sent, thus this file has to be a separate PHP file.