# my php function cant run when i call it in submit form

Tags: php, html, function

I have a proble: I have a function in the html head, and then in the body I have a form type submit and run the function onsubmit. It seeems I cant reach the function or go to function to insert details to database. I cant complete this idea. Please help me this.

```
<?php
function sida() { 
   $host = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $databasename = "vinhcv_truonghoc";
   $connect = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
   $db = mysql_select_db($databasename);
   if (isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {
       $comment = $_POST['comment'];
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $q = "insert into comments values('', '$name', '$comment', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
       echo $q;
       $insert = mysql_query($q);
       if (!$insert) { echo mysql_error(); }
       $id = mysql_insert_id($insert);

       $select = mysql_query("select name, comment, post_time from comments where name = '$name' and comment='$comment' and id='$id'");

       if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
           $name = $row['name'];
           $comment = $row['comment'];
           $time = $row['post_time'];
      ?>
     <div class="comment_div"> 
       <p class="name">Posted By:<?php echo $name;?></p>
       <p class="comment"><?php echo $comment;?></p>    
       <p class="time"><?php echo $time;?></p>
    </div>
  <?php
       }
       exit;
    }
}
?>
```

and the form in the body:

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="sida()">
  <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Write Your Comment Here....."></tetarea>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Your Name">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
</form>

<div id="all_comments">
  <?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databasename = "vinhcv_truonghoc";

    $connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($databasename);

    $comm = mysql_query("select name,comment,post_time from comments order by post_time desc");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comm))
    {
     $name = $row['name'];
     $comment = $row['comment'];
     $time = $row['post_time'];
   ?>

   <div class="comment_div"> 
      <p class="name">Posted By:<?php echo $name;?></p>
      <p class="comment"><?php echo $comment;?></p> 
      <p class="time"><?php echo $time;?></p>
   </div>

   <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

In the body it can connect to database to get information, that mean not thing wrong when connect with database, so why it cant insert to database?

Comment: You can't call php function like this from html. Please Google for form submit.

Comment: Create new page and give that page href in <form action="test.php" method="post">

Comment: actually i cant run in other page so i make it into 1 page, but still not work

Comment: then just give action blank and remove function. Rather then function just check condition if(!empty($_POST)). Hope you get me. @VirusPTIT

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328354/calling-a-particular-php-function-on-form-submit   check this link

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and removed from PHP 7. Instead use `mysqli_*`

Comment: @user3284463 thanks but mysql_* worked normaly in get data from db. and i tried mysqli_* too but still not work

Comment: @suhailc i tried it but not work too, i dont know why, but i try that example and it work....

Comment: @VirusPTIT Did try out my solution?

Comment: @user3284463 yep, already, it still the same. mysql_ still working normaly:)

Comment: @VirusPTIT what was the solution to your problem?

Comment: @user3284463 i just put insert code into <div id=all comment>, no function, no another page and it works like i think, but i still cant get why i wont work if i do like above,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is commented:-

```
  <form method="POST" ><!-- remove  onsubmit="sida()"-->
  <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Write Your Comment Here....." name = "comment"></textarea><!-- add name attribute -->
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Your Name" name = "username"><!-- add name attribute -->
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
 </form>

  <div id="all_comments">
  <?php
    $data = array(); // define empty array
    if(isset($_POST["comment"]) && isset($_POST["username"])){ // check with posted value not button value
        $host="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $databasename="vinhcv_truonghoc";
        $i = 0; // DEFINE COUNTER
        $connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$databasename); // mysql_* is deprecated so use mysqli_* or PDO
        if($connect){ // IF CONNECTION ESTABLISHED
        $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['comment']); // Prevent from SQL Injection
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']); // Prevent from SQL Injection
            $query = mysqli_query ($connect,"INSERT INTO comments (username,comment) VALUES ('".$username."','".$comment."')"); // check and change table name as well as column name
            if($query){
                echo "Inserted Successfully";
            }else{
                echo "Problem occur in insertion because of".mysqli_error($connect);
            }
            $comm = mysqli_query($connect,"select name,comment,post_time from comments order by post_time desc");
            if($comm){ // IF QUERY EXECUTED
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($comm)){
                    $data[$i]["name"]       =   $row['name']; // ASSIGN VALUES TO THE ARRAY
                    $data[$i]["comment"]    =   $row['comment'];
                    $data[$i]["time"]       =   $row['post_time'];
                    $i++;
                }
            }else{
                echo "Query execution failed because of".mysqli_error($connect);
            }
        }else{
            echo'connection problem because of'.mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }else{
        echo "All fields are need to fill properly";

    }
   ?>
    <?php foreach ($data as $dat){?> <!-- ITERATE THROUGH ARRAY -->
           <div class="comment_div"> 
              <p class="name">Posted By:<?php echo $data['name'];?></p>
              <p class="comment"><?php echo $data['comment'];?></p> 
             <p class="time"><?php echo $data['time'];?></p>
           </div>

    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: i think you misundetstand the problem, problem is i cant insert in the part above, this part to get data from db is worked, thanks

Comment: thank you, your code have alittle wrong that when i run it cant understand line foreach($data.... 
it doesnt know where is it data, is that we must define it again?
but with your style code, put code insert into allcomment div, it work with my code :)

Comment: sr, but now i did it :)

Comment: can i ask alittle  bit more, the $_POST still remain when inserted and it insert again when i refesh that page, so i use this: unset($_POST);
  $_POST = array(); but not work, do you have any idea?

Comment: check the link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690541/best-way-to-avoid-the-submit-due-to-a-refresh-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not passing any parameters to the `$_POST` array. You need to pass the `name` attribute to your input fields. Since you are going to run a PHP server-side function you need to use the `action` attribute.

Like this:

```
 <form method="POST" action="sida()">
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Write Your Comment Here....."></textarea>
  <br>
  <input name="name" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Your Name">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" name="submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
       $host="localhost";
       $username="root";
       $password="";
       $databasename="vinhcv_truonghoc";


          function connect()   {
       global $host,$username,$password,$databasename;
       $con=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("ConnectionFailed");
       mysql_select_db($databasename,$con) or exit ("Failed to connect");
       return $con;       }    


     function iud($query) //Insert,Update,Delete   {
       $con=connect();
       $result=mysql_query($query,$con);
       $n=mysql_affected_rows($con);
       mysql_close($con);
       return $n;   }  


     function select ($query) //Select   {
       $con=connect();
       $result=mysql_query($query,$con);
       mysql_close($con);    return $result;   }   




     if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))   {
       $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
       $comment=$_REQUEST['comment'];
       $query="INSERT INTO `comments`(`name`, `comment`, `post_time`)
       VALUES('$name','$comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
       $n=iud($query); 
       echo $n;       }

     ?>


     <html>   <head></head>   <body>   <form method="GET">    <table>  
   <tr>   <td>Name</td>   <td><Input type="text" name="name" id=""
   class=""   placeholder="Name.."></td>      </tr>
          <tr>   <td>Comment</td>   <td><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Comment  

     Here.."> </textarea></td>    </tr>
          <tr>   <td></td>   <td><Input type="submit" name="submit" id="" class="" value="submit">

     </td>    </tr>
          </table>   </form>
          <!-- Showing Result -->     <table>   <?php   $query="Select * from comments ORDER BY coid DESC"; //Coid Is A Primary Key  
   $result=select($query);   $n=mysql_num_rows($result);   if($n>0)   {
   while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))     extract($data);   }    ?>  
   <tr>       <td><?php echo @$name; ?></td>      </tr>   <tr>   <td><?php
   echo @$comment; ?></td>    </tr>   </table>
              </body>     </html>
   ```

   I hope It will Work For you :)

Comment: Please format your answer properly or approve the edit that is done by other user.