# How to run exec() command on HTML button click?

Tags: php, html, exec, submit

So when I load my HTML page, it automatically runs the `exec()` command by default.
How do I make it so like when it only runs when I press the submit button and not my default?

```
<form action="site.php" method="POST">

  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br> 
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br> 

  <input type="submit" value="Show values">

</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

exec('java -jar "C:\temp\test.jar" -db dbs.zed.bvba.com -h 10.222.222.22 -new 1', $response);
print nl2br(print_r($response, true));

?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a particular PHP function on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328354/calling-a-particular-php-function-on-form-submit)

Comment: You should be _very_ careful when using `exec()`, especially when you are passing user/form input to it. Using it incorrectly could allow people to fully compromise your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check, the form is submitted or not.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   exec('java -jar "C:\temp\test.jar" -db dbs.zed.bvba.com -h 10.222.222.22 -new 1', $response);
   print nl2br(print_r($response, true));
}

?>
```